# ¿Cómo encriptar mi DLL de conexión?

Tags: c#, ofuscación

Tengo una aplicación con una capa llamada conexión para conectarme a una base de datos.

Cuando realizó el instalador genera el DLL para la conexión donde se puede ver el usuario y contraseña de mi Base de Datos.

Quisiera encriptar el contenido del DLL para que no puedan ver el usuario y contraseña, pero que mi aplicación siga funcionando normal.

Comment: Encriptar, probablemente quieras ofuscar, es así Andy?

Comment: ¿por que almacenas una contraseña en un dll?

Comment: Ofuscar a que te refieres.

Comment: Lo almacenó en un DLL porque Nose de otro método más seguro

Comment: Ofuscación: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuscaci%C3%B3n

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que "cuando realizo el instalador genera el DLL"? Dudo mucho que tengas un `.msi` o `.exe` como instalador que en uno de los pasos del asistente te pida los datos de la conexión y como paso final **compile el código fuente** incluyendo la cadena de conexión que se ha ingresado. O ¿te refieres a que la cadena de conexión está harcodeada en el código fuente y al compilarse se almacena en el DLL?

Comment: no hay un modo seguro de hardcodear una contraseña, incluso si la encriptas, ¿donde guardarías la clave para desencriptarla? ¿en la dll? estas en el mismo problema, siempre habrá un modo de obtenerla, esto solo lo hace mas difícil. Por otra parte, si quieres proteger tu _backend_, identifica a cada usuario por separado; con usuario y contraseña, uno para cada usuario.

Comment: Hay un método seguro para [Proteger la información de conexión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/89211k9b.aspx) , incluso varias opciones desde la autenticación integrada, hasta de cifrar la cadena de conexion para que solo en dicha maquina se puede "desencriptar" (sin utilizar ni recordar claves) (utiliza API de protección de datos (DPAPI) disponible en Microsoft Windows 2000 y sistemas operativos posteriores)

Comment: @Andynawe por favor revisa los aportes que te han dado y marca alguna como respuesta.

Answer (score 11):

Bueno... Si bien tu pregunta es exclusivamente de "protección una DLL", te comento los problemas/puntos a ver al encriptar o ofuscar. Y la alternativa con la encriptación de cadenas de conexión en un archivo de configuración que es la que te recomiendo que le des una mirada.

**¿Encriptar la DLL ?** No la vas a poder utilizar si no la desencriptas primero. O sea otro app (o assemblie exe que se encargue de eso y lo deje en memoria disponible) Mucho mas trabajo.

**¿Ofuscar la DLL para no ver la password?** No se si "ofuscar" el código del assemblie la DLL no te deja legible el "string" que contiene tu password interna (seguramente habra productos que también ofusquen cadenas internas pero me parece que no es la solución)

**Generalmente como lo utilizamos**

Si tu aplicación se esta ejecutando en una máquina (y/o servidor) la misma puede ser una app web o app win/consola, etc... Y tiene componentes reutilizables o no (assemblies dll) y debemos conectarnos a un base de datos... utilizamos en el archivo de configuración correspondiente (según la app puede ser el app.config o web.config) la sección de [ConnectionString/Cadena de Conexion de dicho archivo de configuración](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494.aspx)
Ejemplo

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="StarwarsDB" 
   providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
    connectionString="aquí va la cadena de conexión valida;" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

(incluso alli podrias utilizar aqui una cadena a la db con autenticacion integrada es decir el usuario que esta impersonando la app es el que tiene acceso a la DB y no enviar así usuario/contraseña)

**Ahora bien si utilizas usuario/contraseña... sigue visible en el archivo de configuración! Si alguien tiene acceso al servidor y al archivo lo podrá visualizar**

Para eso puedes ver ["Cifrar secciones del archivo de configuración mediante una configuración protegida"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494.aspx)

(NOTA: Generalmente vas a ver que todo esta relacionado con web.config para configurar esto en app web, pero sirve para app.config al hacerlo directamente sobre una carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo de configuración)

Para encriptar:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "{Carpeta-donde-se-encuentra-archivo-configuracion}"
```

Ejemplo en imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACLARACION!:** Aqui como es una herramienta para web.config si el archivo app.config es el que esta en la carpeta te generara un archivo web.config separado (para tenerlo en cuenta)

En el ejemplo anterior una vez que ejecutemos, la seccion de cadena de conexion quedaria algo asi (no legible por mas que abras el archivo) y solo se puede descriptar en dicha maquina... **y lo mejor "automáticamente" (no debes hacer nada en tu aplicacion, es transparente)**

```
 <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>fyOBtyVwZ+KY9ziSRKhO5KnoJzX2bm2+ZtAqe+yT03O+Je2yTYwQV66ncXQzmLbO7rekjg5yDYPLAt1cGE7rhCBBwP4y4F7eFj7DXXD6npd5KwlrNfqsr0M/N9Pc5oFw6qxeCgXFkJt1w+T6Tu3XMapxT0jW82Hv6ES+IpqTMFcuEiytzdBKiVkTImzaZvYfOQ2ICXJCY8LChKIRjyWbvv6mU3hxRkBIpvEge1l6suARtfCIzURMTy5/caXPO6KsJQRv62wSeoUtkGjAKwSxEa3Yh9dZ6wArHVnjUdsAsAmxqfmp1cgHX/ZhOhixXviyLwk9DK5dJTxfdFP2pgkhGw==</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
            </EncryptedKey>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>UlL896UHVbNqa9XZN4KTM+Ba3TjEn7b5QiPdkaCe+bQ=</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

Bueno... Sintesis

- Es recomendable que tu código sea agnóstico a la configuración. Por eso la misma debe estar afuera del mismo (de los assmblies) y configurarlo pro archivo o incluso por la DB (pero en algun lado debería estar la cadena de la DB)
- Utiliza las secciones de los archivos de configuracion de .NET y asi puedes encriptar dicha seccion
- Al encriptar por la herramienta, lo debes hacer en la maquina donde se encuentra el archivo de configuración. Ya que solo se podra descriptar automáticamente en dicha maquina
- No hay que compartir claves, ya que utiliza (utiliza API de protección de datos (DPAPI) disponible en Microsoft Windows 2000 y sistemas operativos posteriores)
- Es muy facil de utilizarlo en nuestra app. Transparente.

Contras

- Si es una app de escritorio y debes instalarla masivamente. Aquí hay que ver un mecanismo para esta instalación masiva (Pero igual modo tendrías este inconveniente con los métodos anteriores)

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guía

- [Cadenas de conexión y archivos de configuración](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494.aspx)
- [Cómo: Proteger cadenas de conexión al utilizar controles de orígenes de datos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dx0f3cf2.aspx)
- [Herramienta Registro de IIS en ASP.NET (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: +1 Respuesta muy completa!

Answer (score 1):

No es recomendable almacenar las contraseñas de forma interna en un dll, pero si no hay otra opción podrías añadir mas seguridad en la conexión con el servidor como un túnel ssh y/o validar los certificados de conexión así solo tu aplicación podría consultar la base de datos por mas que tengan la contraseña.

Se recomienda siempre en proyectos .net ofuscar el código final ya que al usar un código intermedio es relativamente fácil su decompilacion.

Puedes usar http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview

Answer (score 1):

De plano tienes un problema de arquitectura.Tu aplicación cliente **NO DEBERIA** acceder directamente a la base de datos.

Lo que pretendes optimizar realmente está escondiendo el verdadero problema de fondo.

Puedes recibir 100 formas diferentes de hacer lo que quieres, pero a la final no vas a solucionar el problema de fondo, solo lo esconderás.

### El problema

Quieres esconder la información de la cadena de conexión, pero esto es imposible, si alguien quiere conectarse por otro mecanismo diferente de tu aplicación logrará hacerlo.

Encriptar la cadena de conexión en el archivo de configuración parece ser una buena idea, pero no lo es. Si la cadena se encuentra encriptada tu ejecutable debe saber como desencriptarla y allí tenemos dos cosas importantes.

1. Si haces encripción de la mala el algoritmo está en tu código y fácilmente con cualquier dissasembler obtienes el código de desencriptación y tienes los datos de conexión de nuevo.
2. Si lo cifras "bien" necesitarás un juego de llaves de encripción, bueno particularmente la llave de desencripción así que esta debe estar anexa o embebida a tu programa, lo cual quiere decir que de nuevo un atacante puede obtenerla fácilmente y obtener el texto claro de la cadena de conexión.

No hay forma de proteger realmente una cadena de conexión alojada localmente, un atacante serio **puede hacerse a ella muy facilmente**.

### Solución REAL

Bueno tienes 2,

#### La más rápida en tu caso

Es delegar acceso a la BD por cada usuario, para ello el usuario debe autenticarse con su "user and password" cada vez que inicia la aplicación, de esta forma la información de autenticación pertenece a cada usuario y no quedaría almacenada y vulnerable localmente.

Esta es la alternativa que usan algunos RAD populares usados aún hoy en día como por ejemplo Oracle Forms.

#### La ideal

Diseñar el software como se diseña el software moderno, distribuido a través de capas lógicas y físicas.

Monta una capa de servicio, una aplicación web contestando peticiones REST por ejemplo, es decir un backend Web API, o bien uno con WCF.

Esta capa requiere autenticación, de nuevo con protocolos modernos como OAuth 2. El usuario inicia su aplicación , esta le pide autenticar, la autenticación se valida contra el servicio y se usan las mismas credenciales (via OAuth Token) para hacer peticiones REST al backend.

El backend es por ende el único que tiene acceso directo a la BD, con credenciales que solo son conocidas por el para realizar sus operaciones de BD de acuerdo a las necesidades del servicio.

A diferencia de la solución rápida, los usuarios acá no son usuarios de BD, por ende no hay riesgo de que usen sus credenciales para conectarse a la BD y saltar validaciones del sistema.

Estos son usuarios de un directorio que puede ser tan sencillo o sofisticado como requieras, estas credenciales solo le permiten conectarse al sistema a operar sobre las funciones que el sistema expone.

--

Desde luego mi recomendación es que te decantes por la opción 2, si por tiempo o recursos no puedes ahora mismo entonces por la 1. Pero no te vayas por la opción de esconder el problema con el tema de esconder/encriptar los datos de conexión al usuario.

Comment: Muy bueno lo de tokens (utilizo JWT). El otro tome que comentas de claves para desencriptar, con [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms995355.aspx) es posible utilizar la encriptacion de archivos de configuracion transparente (pero como comentas no quita que sea 100% seguro... se pueden robar el disco del servidor o copiarlo) pero si es por el simple hecho de no poder visualizarlo es valido. El resto ya es un problema de seguridad mas serio.

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas opciones para ofuscar tu código, pero **no es recomendable guardar usuario y password**, ya que no hay método infalible a ingeniería inversa.

Si buscas en el [directorio Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=obfuscator&f%5B0%5D.Value=obfuscator&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4) encontraras varias opciones para [ofuscar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuscaci%C3%B3n) tu código.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable ocultar valores que deseas que permanezcan secretos en DLLs. Pero si no te queda mas remedio, puedes usar un ofuscador. Por ejemplo: [EazFuscator](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net)